# Socket java can't receive too much data

Tags: java, sockets, networking

This is my socket implementation:

```
s = new Socket(this.host,this.port);
s.setReceiveBufferSize(2048*2048);
s.setSendBufferSize(2048*2048);
```

And when I receive too much data my data is cropped like this:

```
Recieving Message: {"cmd":"209","args":{"type":1,"messages":[{...},{...},{...},{..{...},{�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������...
```

[EDIT]
I create a class called InputReader that implements a Runnable, this class inside has a run method and a while condition:

```
private class InputReader implements Runnable {
    private DarkStarSocketClient main;
    private InputStream in;
    private boolean disconnected = false;

    public InputReader(DarkStarSocketClient main, InputStream in) {
        this.main = main;
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!disconnected) {
            try {

                byte hi = (byte) in.read();
                if (hi == -1) {
                    main.disconnect();
                    MessageBuffer dummy = new MessageBuffer(new byte[0]);
                    postRequest(dummy);
                    break;
                }
                byte lo = (byte) in.read();
                int len = ((hi & 255) << 8) + (lo & 255) << 0;

                byte[] msgBytes = new byte[len];

                in.read(msgBytes);
                MessageBuffer buf = new MessageBuffer(msgBytes);
                handleApplicationMessage(buf);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the implementation of the function handleApplicationMessage:

```
private void handleApplicationMessage(MessageBuffer msg) throws Exception {
    byte command = msg.getByte();

    switch (command) {
        case SimpleSgsProtocol.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            reconnectKey = msg.getBytes(msg.limit() - msg.position());
            loggedIn = true;
            responseHandler.loggedIn();
            break;
        case SimpleSgsProtocol.LOGIN_FAILURE: {
            String reason = msg.getString();
            responseHandler.loginFailed(reason);
            break;
        }
        case SimpleSgsProtocol.LOGIN_REDIRECT: {
            String host = msg.getString();
            int port = msg.getInt();
           break;
        }
        case SimpleSgsProtocol.SESSION_MESSAGE: {
            checkLoggedIn();
            byte[] msgBytes = msg.getBytes(msg.limit() - msg.position());
            responseHandler.receivedSessionMessage(msgBytes);
            break;
        }
        case SimpleSgsProtocol.RECONNECT_SUCCESS:
            loggedIn = true;
            reconnectKey = msg.getBytes(msg.limit() - msg.position());
            responseHandler.reconnected();
            break;
        case SimpleSgsProtocol.RECONNECT_FAILURE:
            String reason = msg.getString();
            this.disconnect();
            break;
        case SimpleSgsProtocol.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
            loggedIn = false;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IOException("Unknown session opcode: " + command);
    }
}
```

Comment: show please the code how you recieve data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have a bug in your code.

The most common mistake is to ignore the length of data actually read when you call read. e.g.

```
for(int length; (length = in.read(buffer)) > 0; ) {
    // you must use the actual length and not assume the buffer is always full.
```

If you ignore the length, you assume the whole buffer has useful data when only the start is right.

---

EDIT: As I guessed you are ignoring the length actually read.  The minimum is 1 no matter how big a byte[] you give it.

```
in.read(msgBytes);
```

should be

```
int length = in.read(msgBytes);
// keep reading until you have everything.
```

Your life would be a lot simpler if you used DataOutputStream and DataInputStream

```
 private final DataInputStream in;

 try {
    while (!disconnected) {
        int length = in.readShort() & 0xFFFF;
        byte[] msgBytes = new byte[length];
        in.readFully(msgBytes); // keeps reading until the whole buffer is read.
        try {
            MessageBuffer buf = new MessageBuffer(msgBytes);
            handleApplicationMessage(buf);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 } catch (EOFException expected) {

 } catch (Throwable t) {
    System.err.println("Fatal error");
    t.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: I have a problem with my function handleApplicationMessage. It always ends in unknown session opcode case. I will edit my question.

Comment: 1. Do you think it is necessary to reconnect socket in the catch of EOFException? 
2. It is normal that I still receive data when the EOFException is catched?

Comment: Whether you reconnect depends on your requirements. If you got some data before the EOF it means the writer didn't send as much data as you expected.